# Show project indexes when building VS Solution with MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2019

When building a Soultion with Visual Studio, each line is marked with an index that corresponds to a particular procees project:

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: rootProject, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
2>------ Build started: Project: SkypeDLAPI_IDL, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
3>------ Build started: Project: NLHCLib, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
4>------ Build started: Project: AprDLAPI_IDL, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
5>------ Build started: Project: DLServiceCMN, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
6>------ Build started: Project: SkypeProfile, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
7>------ Build started: Project: DLRes, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
8>------ Build started: Project: DLMessages, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
2>Processing .\RpcNetworkLock.idl
2>RpcNetworkLock.idl
6>spAccounts.cpp
6>spConversations.cpp
```

However, when I run `MSBuild.exe`

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\msbuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\msbuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe" "DeviceLock_vs2019.sln" /p:PreferredToolArchitecture=x64 /p:Configuration="Debug" /p:Platform="Win32" /t:build  /maxcpucount:6 /verbosity:Minimal /fileLogger1 /fileloggerparameters1:ErrorsOnly;LogFile="C:/Users/sergey.kolesnik/dev/repos/DLP/main/src/all.log";Verbosity=Minimal;Encoding=ASCII; /fileLogger2 /fileloggerparameters2:ErrorsOnly;Append;LogFile="C:/Users/sergey.kolesnik/dev/repos/DLP/main/src/\all_Debug_Win32.err";Encoding=ASCII;  /filelogger4 /fileloggerparameters4:LogFile="C:/Users/sergey.kolesnik/dev/repos/DLP/main/src/\all_Debug_Win32.det";Verbosity=normal;ShowCommandLine=no /ds
```

I don't get such formating. Lines are not indexed and it is very hard to understand which project a processed source file belongs to:

```
  FileTypeDetector_vs2019.vcxproj -> C:\Users\sergey.kolesnik\dev\repos\DLP\main\src\Out_2019\x86\Debug\FileTypeDetecto
  r\FileTypeDetector.lib
  ElasticClient_vs2019.vcxproj -> C:\Users\sergey.kolesnik\dev\repos\DLP\main\src\Out_2019\x86\Debug\ElasticClient\Elas
  ticClient.lib
  RemoteInstall_vs2019.vcxproj -> C:\Users\sergey.kolesnik\dev\repos\DLP\main\src\Out_2019\x86\Debug\RemoteInstall\Remo
  teInstall.lib
  TextUtils_vs2019.vcxproj -> C:\Users\sergey.kolesnik\dev\repos\DLP\main\src\Out_2019\x86\Debug\TextUtils\TextUtils.li
  b
  AlertSenderSmtp.cpp
  FontGetter.cpp
  PdfShadower.cpp
  PrinterEnumCallbacks.cpp
  PrinterHlp.cpp
  EventLog.cpp
  PrinterHook.cpp
  netresident.cpp
  AuditRecord.cpp
  PrinterNameCache.cpp
  RemoteDataProcess.cpp
  PrinterProcessor.cpp
  hooks_srv_utils.cpp
  hooks_utils.cpp
  ShadowPdfMerger.cpp
  iphone_cfbinary.cpp
  ClipboardData.cpp
  settings.cpp
  ClipboardDevice.cpp
  ClipboardResCache.cpp
```

1. Are there any CLI parameters for `MSBuild.exe` that would make the logging output like when a Solution is built with Visual Studio?
2. Is there an option to print a list of failed projects at the end?

Comment: Here is the [MSBuild Command-Line Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2022). There seems to be no command line to display an index like "1>,2>,3>" and print a list of failed projects at the end.

Answer (score 1):

The 'index' is a 'project key'. Project keys are generated per build and within a build are unique per project. (See related "[Do the 1>, 2>, 3> symbols in msbuild output stand for threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72334143/do-the-1-2-3-symbols-in-msbuild-output-stand-for-threads)")

There doesn't seem to be a documented switch to enable showing the project keys.

However I did some quick tests that are summarized in the following table:

| Cmd | OS | Project Ids in the Log? | MSBuild version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `msbuild` | Windows | No | 17.3 |
| `dotnet msbuild` | Windows | Yes | 17.3 |
| `msbuild` | macOS | Yes | 16.10 |
| `dotnet msbuild` | macOS | Yes | 16.10 |

This shows that a work-around is to run MSBuild via the `dotnet` command. This doesn't require any changes in your code. The `dotnet` tool is just a host for the MSBuild engine. The same is true of Visual Studio (`devenv.exe`). As hosts for MSBuild, `dotnet` and `devenv` are enabling the Project key in the logging.

MSBuild will list all warnings and errors at the end of the log but there is no option to generate a list of the failed projects.

The summary line that appears in the Visual Studio build output (like the following example) is generated by Visual Studio and doesn't come from MSBuild.

```plaintext
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```